# Adding a Image Upload Button in CKEditor

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

I have installed CKEditor in Wysiwyg profiles. While publishing any node if i click on the image upload button it shows options to add images by a image link, but what is the way to add a dynamic image upload button so that users will be able to Browse and choose any image from their computer in content?

Answer (score 7):

Check out [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) with [IMCE WYSIWYG bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg).

Once you install and configure those two modules, select "IMCE" as a button in CKEditor and then you can upload and insert images in WYSIWYG.

Comment: two issues , first one is it shows a server upload and in that frame i got a upload button, so is there any way to use the only Browse button, and second issue is though the photo uploaded successfully in wysiwyg body but after save the content uploaded photos get disappear ,, ?

Comment: 1) IMCE allows you to *browse* the files on the server. That is why you get the second upload button. This is good if your files are already on the server or if you want to use the same file in several pages for example. Otherwise you would have to upload a file each time you want to use it - which is not good from management point of view. 2) Check your text input filter and if it supports the img tag.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm somewhat late to this question, but I just found out about [One Click Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/ocupload) which does exactly what you want and may help others that have this same problem and arrive to this question (the only caveat is that it needs flash to be enabled to work).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use according plugins: http://doksoft.com/soft/ckutils/index.html
It allows user to upload images, preview and re-size uploaded images when needed.

Comment: I am afraid the plugins are not free.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module but it is much more than a simple image uploader and you should use it only if you want to be able to manage files through Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

in drupal 7 you can work with ckeditor and imce modules.
after you've installed these two modules:

1. in imce config, under "Configuration profiles" you can add new profile and edit it's setting and under "Directories" add directories that you want the user access and add images.
2. go back to imce config page and under "Role-profile assignments" attach a role that the user have to the profile that you've created.
3. then go to ckeditor config page. profile advance -> edit. under file browsing setting, set "File the browser type" to imce.

that's it . now the user can click on picture icon on ckeditor and upload a new image in directories that you've set.

hope it helps.